# Silly math pb with php pagination

Tags: php, math, pagination

I need to find what the actual page of a search result in php. 
To know that , i have 3 informations :
the total number of item result ( 225 )
the number of item per page (24 )
the item position ( 9 )

In this case, i am on page 1 , What the mathematic operation to find 
whats the actual page if position item is 36 ?

thanks for your help,
jess

Comment: no its for my php code ,i bug , i tryed some division but its pity

Comment: seems not so simple as i thought...

Comment: @ MArk , its not correct.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ceil(resultNumber/resultsPerPage)  //ceil(36/24)
```